# USB camera to Fast Ethernet

Tags: networking, usb, ethernet, connector, connection

I have an USB camera from Microsoft that is too far away from the computer(10 meters along the wall) that I want to connect to.

And as we know that the maximum length of an USB 2.0 cable can be 7 meters I purchased
2 x USB to Fast Ethernet adapters and used one to plug the usb camera into the wall RJ-45 port and
one from the table where the computer is to switch back from RJ-45 to USB.

I used a normal patch cord to connect the 2 ports in the patch panel.

But it does not work: it says the device is not recognized.

What can be the problem: should I try different patch cord wiring ?

Another problem might be the distance between the 2 ports: from one to another through the patch panel
it may be over 100 meters.

I am open to suggestions :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I purchased 2 x USB to Fast Ethernet adapters

The "USB Ethernet adapters" that I'm familiar with have a USB A connector for the host side, and are totally unsuited for connection to a USB camera.  It has to be connected to a PC host, not a USB gadget.

There are some USB-to-CAT5 transformers/baluns, but then the UTP cable must be dedicated to that connection and be excluded from the Ethernet network.  That also means that there cannot be any Ethernet switches or hubs between the two transformers; there has to be a point-to-point electrical connection.

> I am open to suggestions

What about an ***active USB extension cable***, which are offered in 5 and 10 meter lengths, and can be cascaded?

Comment: I had never heard of a active USB extension cable before, looks cool, I found a 10 meter cable (exactly what the OP needs) for only $13 [on Amazon](http://www.amazon.com/Active-Extension-Repeater-Female-Meters/dp/B002VG39BI).

Comment: Thank you sawdust. I purchased a 5 meter active USB extension cable but the video quality is deprecated.

Comment: Sorry to hear that.  The quality of the cable&electronics could make a difference.  Some USB active cables at amazon.com have a mix of good and bad reviews, but I did see one "USB2.0 16-Feet Certified Active Extension Cable" that had more than a hundred all 5 & 4-star reviews and _no_ bad reviews.  Several reviewers mention that they are successfully using it with a USB camera. YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

Your USB/Ethernet solution won't work because the voltage drop along that length of cable is too great. Simple solution for 10m connection is two 5m cables and a powered hub in the middle.

Comment: A "powered hub" would require an (external) power source, whereas an active extension cable does not.  So maybe it's a simple solution, but not the simplest solution.